# MySQL joining multiple sql results when all data is in one table

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I have a table containing lots of data with several fields including:

```
day (Monday ~ Sunday)
City (NY, LA, FL, etc.)
```

I would like to use php to make a table to display totals like this:

```
  --- Mon --- Tue --- Wed ...
NY    6       8       9
LA    7       5       3
FL    1       0       4
```

But I am having trouble to write the SQL to make this work. I have used union but that appends the result at the bottom, so it seems I need to use inner join, or not even it. The two queries that I can get remotely close to what I want are:

`select city, count(id) as 'Monday' from index where city = "NY" and day = 'Monday' group by city
union all 
select city, count(id) as 'Monday' from index where city = 'LA' and day = 'Monday' group by city
union all 
select city, count(id) as 'Monday' from index where city = 'FL' and day = 'Monday' group by city`

This produces the following result

> --- Mon 
>   NY    6 
>   LA        7        
>   FL        1

The problem with this is I don't know how to add the rest of the days to the right of it

Another query I have tried is 
`select a.day, a.counts as 'NY', b.counts as 'LA' from 
(select day, count(id) as counts from index where city='NY' GROUP BY DAY) as a 
left join 
(select day, count(id) as counts from index where city='LA' GROUP BY DAY) as b 
on (a.day = b.day) 
order by field (a.day, 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')`

This produces the following result

> NY --- LA --- 
>   Monday      6        7
>   Tuesday        8        5

And the problem with this one is the row and column should be swapped, also I don't know how to add another city (I have many cities).

All the data is in one table called "index". Could someone give me the guidance on how to write the SQL? I would also need the field to show 0 or Null when there is no record. The end goal is to produce the table with PHP.

Thank you for taking the time to read and answer.

Comment: `select city, count(id) as 'count' from index where city IN('NY','LA','FL') and day  IN('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday') group by city`

Comment: This is called a *pivot* operation. It's fiddly to get right in MySQL, but it can be done. There are plenty of examples on the toobz.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem's like you want to `pivot` the data by the `day` and `group` it by `City`. If this then you can try the following query may this help.

```
select city, 
sum(case when (day = 'Monday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Monday',
sum(case when (day = 'Tuesday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Tuesday',
sum(case when (day = 'Wednesday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Wednesday',
sum(case when (day = 'Thursday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Thursday',
sum(case when (day = 'Friday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Friday',
sum(case when (day = 'Saturday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Saturday',
 sum(case when (day = 'Sunday') then  1 else 0 end)  'Sunday'

from `index` group by city
```

Comment: Haha. Jinks mate!

Comment: haha, seems like an exact copy but not ever used it before in circle ara.@CaioSym

Comment: This produces the exact intended result. It takes a few minutes to solve something that have been puzzling me for a few days. It's incredible. Thank you addy very much, and all the other people who took the time to comment.

Comment: More concisely:  `SUM(day = 'Monday') AS 'Monday'` since a boolean is treated as 1 or 0.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have your schema so I'm taking a few liberties. You probably want something like this:

Ps: Depending on your db you may be able to replace the sum(case...) with the proper sumif function

```
SELECT 
  city,
  sum(case when day = 'Monday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Monday',  
  sum(case when day = 'Tuesday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Tuesday',  
  sum(case when day = 'Wednesday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Wednesday',  
  sum(case when day = 'Thursday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Thursday',  
  sum(case when day = 'Friday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Friday',  
  sum(case when day = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Saturday',  
  sum(case when day = 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Sunday'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY city
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how that had gotten there